# Using Klocwork to analyze an iOS app in mac

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-analysis, klocwork

I have to do static analysis of an iPhone app using Klocworks.
I have installed Klockworks on mac os X and the project is written using XCode.

But I don't have developer certificates (and dont want to buy them, as i only want to do static analysis). Using xocdebuild command is not building the app.

Can someone please tell me how to do do static analysis of xcode projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps I can save you some time here. Klocwork Insight can be installed on Mac OS/X but as with other platforms on which we install, it supports C/C++ and Java (plus C# on Windows). We do not support analysis of Objective-C as would presumably be required for your iOS application.

Note that XCode has the LLVM static analyzer built in (one of the main actions in XCode is Build and Analyze), which whilst not particularly deep, does some very nice contract-based analysis and does, after all, support Objective-C and the iOS frameworks.

Regards,
Gwyn Fisher
CTO and VP R&D, Klocwork Inc.